# Joining two tables and merging the common columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, join, outer-join

I have 2 mysql tables:

```
t1 with columns as follows:
customer, datetime, products1
t2 with columns as follows:
customer, datetime, products2
t1: customer  datetime             products1  country
    111       2018-11-23 01:12:33    p1         A
    111       2018-11-23 01:13:00    p2         A   
    112       2018-11-23 01:12:12    p1         B
    112       2018-11-23 01:15:10    p3         B


t2: customer  datetime             products2
    111       2018-11-23 01:12:40    q1
    111       2018-11-23 01:13:00    q2
    112       2018-11-23 01:12:10    q1
    112       2018-11-23 01:15:20    q3
```

I would like to join both as doing and outer join with mysql and get only 1 datetime, 1 customer and merge both products and finally order by datetime. So I want something like this:

```
 customer         datetime              products    country
  112             2018-11-23 01:12:10     q1          NULL
  112             2018-11-23 01:12:12     p1          B
  111             2018-11-23 01:12:33     p1          A
  111             2018-11-23 01:12:40     q1          NULL
  111             2018-11-23 01:13:00     p2          A
  111             2018-11-23 01:13:00     q2          NULL
  112             2018-11-23 01:15:10     p3          B
  111             2018-11-23 01:13:00     q2          NULL
```

I am just wondering about how to merge the two datetimes into only one  and same for products.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no common data between the two tables, I think you want a `UNION`, not a `MERGE`. Try this:

```
SELECT
  customer,
  datetime,
  products1 as products,
  country
FROM t1
UNION
SELECT
  customer,
  datetime,
  products2 as products,
  null as country
FROM t2
```

Comment: Your solution works well but union is too slow despite the fact that the customer and datetime are indexed. Any suggestions to speed it up?

Comment: A `SELECT` without a `WHERE` clause is about the simplest query you can make, so any improvements will likely come from tuning your mysql environment, not improving the query. See some ideas here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-optimization.html